# How to save multiple Entities with relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have 3 Entities, meetingSetting, meetingDate and time. MeetingSettingsId is referenced in both entities date and time. time also have dateId as a reference. I know want to send such a json to my backend:

```
{
   "meetingName":"hallo",
   "meetingUrl":"",
   "meetingPw":"s",
   "dates":"2021-05-30",
   "times":[
      {
         "startTime":"15:30",
         "endTime":"16:30"
      },
      {
         "startTime":"18:30",
         "endTime":"19:30"
      }
   ]
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
   not-null property references a null or transient value : com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.times.Time.meetingDate
```

I want to save with one method meetingSetting witht the shown json.

This is how my entities look:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "meeting_date")
    @Data
    public class Date {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "meeting_date")
        private String date;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingDate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Time> meetingTime = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_settings_name", nullable = false)
        private MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting;
    
@JsonCreator
public static Date fromDateAsString(String dateString){
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate(dateString);
    return date;
}    


}
```

meetingSettingEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Data

public class MeetingsSetting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name")
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingsSetting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Date dates = new Date();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meetingsSetting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Time> times = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

and finally time:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Data
public class Time {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_settings_name", nullable = false)
    private MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_date_id")
    private Date meetingDate;

}
```

this is the save method I am using and here probably the error occurs. I guess I kind of have to tell to save time and date too if I am not wrong, but I did not know how to do it the service method calls the save from a jparepository:

```
   @PostMapping("/")
    public void saveMeeting(@RequestBody MeetingsSetting meetingsSetting){
        meetingSettingService.saveMeeting(meetingsSetting);

    }
```

Comment: I had noticed a few errors myself and updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you are providing dates field as a String, but in the backend model it's represented as Object of type Date.

You have to make sure your backend model represent your json, by for example introduce DTOs ( Data Transfert Object ) that matches your json model and then map to your entities.
However, if you are just developing this application for tests or as a proof of concept. Here a working solution, just add this method in your Date.java class :

```
@JsonCreator
public static Date fromDateAsString(String dateString){
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setDate(dateString);
    return date;
}
```

The idea here is to help [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (which is the library responsible for deserializing json to Java Object) to create a Date Instance from the String provided in json.

Comment: Hi Thanks, this helped me out but now I get a new error, I updated my question. Could you maybe help me with that too? it is this error: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.cbc.coorporateblinddateservice.entities.times.Time.meetingDate